# How to process csv data (datetime) month, week, day, hour in highstock highcharts

Tags: csv, highcharts, navigator

I have a CSV file with following format:

```
<pre id="csv" style="display:none">
DATES,WHOLESALE,ECOMMERCE,RETAIL,LOANS,BONDISSUER
01/10/2018 00:00,25,16,13,1,0
01/10/2018 01:00,24,5,9,3,2
01/10/2018 02:00,28,6,17,0,6
```

The data range is 01/10/2018 00:00 -  31/10/2018 00:00
Interval is every hour.
I am using highstock stacked column with 5 categories: WHOLESALE,ECOMMERCE,RETAIL,LOANS,BONDISSUER. 
My problem is, that the highstock navigator displays the data incorrectly. I think I have to customise property in range selector or navigator, but I can't find any documentation online. I tried inputDateParser, but it didn't work. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marialaustsen/tumfhsjb/10/)

```
inputDateParser: function (value) {
        value = value.split(/[:\.]/);
        return Date.UTC(
            1970,
            0,
            1,
            parseInt(value[0], 10),
            parseInt(value[1], 10),
            parseInt(value[2], 10),
            parseInt(value[3], 10)
        );
    }
```

How do I get the data range to be correct: month of October 2018 according to the dates in CSV?
I should not see a whole year in the navigator, when I only have data for October. 
Thanks much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to format the dates correctly, it can be done using the `beforeParse` callback function, like this:

```
data: {
  csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
  beforeParse: function(e) {
    let csv = e.split('\n'); //split by newline
    let processedTable = []
    processedTable.push(csv[0].split(','))
    for (let i = 1; i < csv.length; i++) {
      let row = csv[i].split(',');
      if (row.length != 6) //skip empty rows or rows with more/less columns
        continue;
      let date = row[0].split(' ')[0].split('/')
      let time = row[0].split(' ')[1].split(':')

      processedTable.push(
        [(new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0], time[0], time[1], 0)).getTime(), //get the timestamp for the date 
          parseInt(row[1]),
          parseInt(row[2]),
          parseInt(row[3]),
          parseInt(row[4]),
          parseInt(row[5])
        ].join(',')
      )
    }
    return processedTable.join('\n') //join the array into a string again
  },
},
```

Every row is parsed, by splitting it apart, the date is found, and milliseconds since 1970 is returned by `getTime()`. Then we join the cells into strings, and lastly the rows into a long string. The reason we convert this back into a string, is because highcharts is going to read it in from a string.

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/spmtgv3a/

**API on beforeParse:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.beforeParse

Comment: thank you. I have updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marialaustsen/tumfhsjb/         Now also with rangeSelector button types.